# don't scale normally animation android

Tags: android, scale, android-animation

I want to create a animation that goes like this :
It scales from the bottom left corner to the top right corner.

Here's my code so far :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    >
</scale>

</set>
```

Is there some tutorial on how to do animations ? I understand the concept but i don't know all the variables, like pivotX and pivotY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is use pivotX and pivotY :

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    >
</scale>
```

pivots are the starting points of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... [Animation Tutorial on CogitoLearning](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=877)

Answer (score 0):

here i set the animation to image
create new folder named **anim** in your **res** directory and save the animation xml

use `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.xmlname);`

```
private Animation animFadeIn;
ImageView image;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image);
animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.xmlname);
image.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
```